# Append characters at any place between string

Tags: java

I have a String and I wanted to append a string(numeric) value in between it.
How can I do it?

I did this but it doesn't work for me.

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id","id");

String url = "http://192.168.33.197:8000/news/api/list-news/?q=" + data + "&format=json";

String url2 = "http://192.168.33.197:8000/news/api/list-news/?q=\" + data + \"&format=json";
```

In the first case, I got this->

```
 http://192.168.33.197:8000/news/api/list-news/?q=2
```

In the second case, I got this->

```
http://192.168.33.197:8000/news/api/list-news/?q=" + data + "&format=json
```

But I want this ->

```
http://192.168.33.197:8000/news/api/list-news/?q=2&format=json
```

PS: data = "2" here!

Comment: The first case should be correct. Check that your posted code accurately reflects the tested code.

Comment: I don't know why but "&format=json" is not appending at the end of the string in the first case.

Comment: And I'm telling you it is, and your error is elsewhere. `class Test { public static void main(String args[]) { String data = "2"; String url = "http://192.168.33.197:8000/news/api/list-news/?q=" + data + "&format=json"; System.out.println(url); } }`, save as `Test.java`, compile with `javac Test.java`, run with `java Test`.

Comment: How are you using/printing strings (knowing their values)? Could data contain new line character?

Comment: May you should use `StringBuilder` instead

Comment: @TaQuangTu Javac will convert the concatenation to a StringBuilder already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this right format for the url string :

```
String data = "2";
String url = "http://192.168.33.197:8000/news/api/list-news/?q=" + data + "&format=json";       
System.out.println(url);
```

Output :

```
http://192.168.33.197:8000/news/api/list-news/?q=2&format=json
```